# Maui IOS adding network extension

Tags: ios, .net-core, maui, .net-ios

I'm trying to add an IOS target extension to a MAUI application, I am not finding the Xamarin project template for this IOS extension type, dose anyone know if there is any workaround?!

Comment: Please explain the problem so that it's comprehensible. What exactly is the issue? Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: FYI: I see [iOS Network Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension) is Apple *Prerelease* (Beta software). [Apple's sample code for Xcode](https://github.com/ios-sample-code/SimpleTunnel). Add a new issue at [github dotnet runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime) asking if there is a way to access these Beta APIs from `.Net for iOS`. [It has to be handled in the .Net iOS runtime; not a "Maui" technology, though I'm keeping the Maui tag because people tend to search that when they mean "using .Net on different platforms".]